# Boxing Corkscrew Punch: Is it the default punch?

Tags: training, technique, boxing, punching

Is the "Corkscrew punch" the defacto/regular punch in boxing? It seems like most boxers are doing this anyways in their jab/cross punch, where wrist is rotated and thumb is slightly angled down. Or is the corkscrew punch a totally different from other jabs/crosses they teach in boxing? This question is more about dictionary terminology in boxing.

"Corkscrew punch requires you to rotate your entire arm, right from the shoulder to the elbow, all the way to your fist. The term Corkscrew punch was invented by a popular boxer Charles “Kid” McCoy, active between 1891-1916."

Wing Chun and Krav Maga teach slightly different rotations in boxing.

Resources:
a) https://lawofthefist.com/all-inclusive-guide-to-corkscrew-punch-in-boxing-2/

b) https://expertboxing.com/corkscrew-punch-technique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term 'corkscrew punch' is familiar, yet I have never heard any boxing coach employ it when teaching how to strike.

As your link from Expert Boxing states, rotating the wrist to horizontal when punching is normal.

Rotating beyond this point is typical mainly during overhand punches, as the extra rotation allows for the elbow to be raised sufficiently to enable these strikes.

If by 'default punch', you mean 'typical' or 'standard' for the foundational boxing techniques of jabs and straight crosses, then yes, such rotation is orthodox. In other words, it is normal to rotate one's fist in such a fashion unless the circumstances warrant a different technique.

More detail relevant to this question is available in the answers you received in response to your previous question about [which way to rotate knuckles](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/12928/punching-which-way-to-rotate-knuckles).

Comment: this link also explains about rotating shoulder and elbow;  so the corkscrew punch is just a regular punch? interesting, they make it sound like its a different punch, I just had a question about boxing dictionary terms, not really about technique, thanks

Comment: https://lawofthefist.com/all-inclusive-guide-to-corkscrew-punch-in-boxing-2/

Comment: by the way, I left a general forum question here, thank you for all the answers, https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/664/rename-name-of-this-forum-or-gain-more-web-activity